# Ходил в поход на Псков (в 1124). Нужно ли слово "год"?

Tags: грамматика, стилистика, числительные

Допустимо ли опускать слово "год" в таких случаях?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В разговорном стиле можно опускать слово "год", но в этом случае нужно при записи использовать буквенное наращение (в 1124-м). [Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

Пришедшие в 1917-м к власти большевики сначала хотели его сохранить, но надо было как-то наполнять бюджет. [Дмитрий Михайлин. Односолодовая водка // «Русский репортер», 2015]

А в 1917-м собор повредили при обстреле Кремля и через год закрыли. [Алесь Пашкевич. Сим победиши // «Сибирские огни», 2013